# Change background image on hover

Tags: html, css, list

Would the proportions of the image have anything to do with the problem?

```
#menu {
background: black;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
}
#menu ul {

text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;

}

#menu li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
font-size: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
#menu a:hover {
   background-image: url(images/hover.png);

}
#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
margin: auto
  background-repeat: bo-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: contain;

}
```

On hover it repeats the images multiple times. The image is 2000 x 500 px. How can I make it so that this image is displayed behind the word in the middle and not repeat. Thank you

This is the image hover
[link](http://s16.postimg.org/nvb98nngl/hover.png)

the html code

```
<div id="menu"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="#"> lalal</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did click the live demo and that was working then when I added and modified the code to suit yours it did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the text parameters like this:

[**LIVE DEMO OF YOUR WEBSITE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Z9Z/5/)

```
#menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: still no luck I think my computer is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `background-repeat` and `background-position` properties using the shorthand notation

```
#menu a:hover {
   background: url(images/hover.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

To allow the whole image to be seen you must modify the CSS for the `li` tag:

```
#menu li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
font-size: 30px;
width: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
height: 40px;
overflow: auto; /* Added this */
}
```

Comment: This does not work as it only shows one small part of the photo :(

Comment: @ridjako Is this `a` within an `li` by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is in a li. I feel as though this should be very simple but. background-size: 100%;, background-repeat and the other things that should stop it arn't so...

Comment: Its because the `li` is styled to have a specific height and width.

Comment: I just removed it and yet no luck

Answer (score 0):

`#menu a:hover {
background: url(images/hover.png) no-repeat center center;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can change only `background-image` instead of all `background` attributes.

```
#menu a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("images/no-hover.png");
}
#menu a:hover {
   background-image: url("images/hover.png");
}
```

This will ingore all `background` proberties (`repeat`, `position` ...) and change only `image`.

This is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/B2Dbf/

Comment: This one is the closest to working but the image repeats its self along the y axis 3 times and its height is 500px with the container only being 50px high

Comment: i'd make mistake, `bo-repeat` to `no-repeat`

Comment: I know I fixed that  :)