# Change background url when div is hovered with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, background-image

What I'm trying to do is swap over a background image when a list item is hovered over.

I've been trying to get .remove and .append working, but I'm running round in circles trying to target the right things and get the syntax right! Is anybody able to please lend a hand?

CSS:

```
 <div class="splash">
    <div class="main_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainUK"><a href="/UK">The UK</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainJapan"><a href="/Japan">Japan</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainChina"><a href="/China">China</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainHK"><a href="/HK">Hong Kong</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainMalaysia"><a href="/Malaysia">Malaysia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

html:

```
.splash { 
  background: url(Assets/Images/Splash/UK.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

The other images are located in the same folder under different names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the CSS of the container with jQuery.  It would look something like this:

```js
$(".main_headings").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".splash").css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/600x400/3366ff/000000")');
});
```

```css
.splash { 
  background: url("http://placehold.it/600x400/ff3366/000000") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="splash">
  <div class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="main_headings" id="mainUK"><a href="/UK">The UK</a></li>
      <li class="main_headings" id="mainJapan"><a href="/Japan">Japan</a></li>
      <li class="main_headings" id="mainChina"><a href="/China">China</a></li>
      <li class="main_headings" id="mainHK"><a href="/HK">Hong Kong</a></li>
      <li class="main_headings" id="mainMalaysia"><a href="/Malaysia">Malaysia</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is very basic... it just shows how to effect the background-image property from jquery.  I assume you'd want to be more specific (ie, having different images with different LIs, and probably setting the background-image back to the original on mouseout), but this should get you started.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm not getting anything. My code looks like:

$(document).ready(function(){

//swap out bg on hover

$('#mainJapan').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.splash').css("background", "url(Assets/Images/Splash/Japan.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;");
});

});

Is it possible that the original background is overriding the hover or something? Or does the hover need to take a second function that tells it to return to the original image?

Comment: I changed my answer to use a snippet so you could see it working.  I also made the jquery/css bit a bit simpler - I think having the whole background shorthand in there was messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2Z9Z/5/

```
#menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

reference.

[Change background image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228248/change-background-image-on-hover)

Comment: unless i'm missing something, the problem with this is i need the .splash image to change, not the list item's bg.

Comment: Can you send the code in jsfiddle, so I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

in my example code I used jQuery to change the css background-image value on mouseenter and mouseout:

```js
$('.splash a').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.splash').css("background-image", "url(http://placehold.it/500x350/bf1)");
});
$('.splash a').mouseout(function() {
  $('.splash').css("background-image", "url(http://placehold.it/499x349/fb7)");
});
```

```css
.splash { 
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x350/fb7);
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="splash">
    <div class="main_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainUK"><a href="/UK">The UK</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainJapan"><a href="/Japan">Japan</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainChina"><a href="/China">China</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainHK"><a href="/HK">Hong Kong</a></li>
        <li class="main_headings" id="mainMalaysia"><a href="/Malaysia">Malaysia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```